# Lost pictures on Samsung Galaxy S3 internal memory

Tags: internal-storage, data-recovery, photos, storage

I just hooked my *Samsung Galaxy S3* up to my PC via USB to transfer some photos from one folder to another on the device itself.  Well, the USB cable got accidentally unplugged during the process, and I lost all the photos that didn't have a chance to transfer before the device got unplugged.

Is there a way to retrieve these photos as I cannot get a drive letter when I plug it in, and Samsung does not offer a Mass Storage Device option for this phone.

I really need to recover these photos. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried checking with a file explorer app directly on your device? Take a look into the `LOST.DIR` directory as well (which is where "lost" files sometimes land -- usually if the system encountered any file-system errors and does not know where the file belongs to, but maybe in your case as well).

Comment: if you have root access, there are file recovery apps, that you can install and they'll scan for deleted files. one of them is called disc digger undelete, another is called hexamob recovery. Also there is android-recovery.net. Neither of those have resulted in anything for my problem though...

Comment: Diskdigger. Plain and simple.